# Why would my object not picked up from BlobStorage by Verizon CDN @ Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

So I have a file as Blob object that is publicly available via the internet. Now I am adding a CDN ("Premium Verizon" tier) and point it to Storage as origin. The full URL path to the object is https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/rocksolid/news/latestnews.html and that works perfectly fine - page is fetched and displayed no problem just by browsing to it.

So hence here is the configuration done:

[image]

Alas that configuration does not work and I only get this error:

```
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:(...)
</Message>
</Error>
```

What am I doing wrong or what could be the issue here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The origin path is like the relative path to the origin.
So if you set "/rocksolid/news" as the Origin path, going to .azureedge.net/latestnews.html will find your file.

The origin path implicitly adds a "/" after your input origin path because it treats it as a directory.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it would still not pick up the file.I only get 404 - not found via azureedge.net/latestnews.html. Is there a certain propagation time for the change to take effect?

Comment: It finally worked - takes quite some propagation time, apparently!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the origin as,

> /rocksolid/news/latestnews.html

and blob as

> xxx.blob.core.windows.net/

and if you request for  http://xxx.azureedge.net/index.html

then it will look for

> xxx.blob.core.windows.net/rocksolid/news/latestnews.html/index.html

So you need to remove,

> latestnews.html

from your path and leave only

> /rocksolid/news/

in your path to work directly from edge.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I assume the trailing / is not needed for the origin path?